# How to store and retrieve places on Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm hoping to develop an app for one of my college projects that offers a service for restaurants to register and store general details, menu, and their restaurant location then I'd like to retrieve these restaurant locations on the Android app I'm working on based on the user's location, So that when a customer open the app, the restaurants near that user in a 5 mile radius is listed,

It would be two different apps for restaurant owners and customers connected to the same database.

I'd like some pointers on how to achieve this task, please feel free to point out best practices if I'm going in the wrong direction to achieve this task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A restaurant will have its location stored as a combination of latitude and longitude in your database.

When a customer opens the application, you have to get the current location of the customer and query your database to check if the distance between the current location of the user / customer and the restaurant location is less than 5 miles. Google has already provided a method to achieve this functionality.

Suppose that you represent the user's location as:

```
Location userLocation = new Location("");
userLocation.setLatitude(latitude1);
userLocation.setLongitude(longitude1);
```

This is how you represent the restaurant's location queried from the database one at a time.

```
Location restaurantLocation = new Location("");
restaurantLocation.setLatitude(latitude2);
restaurantLocation.setLongitude(longitude2);
```

And this way you can calculate the distance in meters.

```
float distanceInMeters = userLocation.distanceTo(restaurantLocation);
```

You can do the appropriate conversion to miles as follows:

```
float distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters / 1.60934
```

And then check if it is more than 5 miles. If the condition returns true, mark that location in the map with the coordinates of the restaurant.

```
if (distanceInMiles > 5)
{
   // code to set the marker with the restaurant's coordinates on the map.
}
```

You can perform this test periodically (say after every 5 minutes), to find the restaurants' in a 5 mile radius near the user.